# How to access SQL Server without using SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

I have two windows servers X and Y.

And I have SQL Server database on Y. X doesn't have SQL Server Management Studio on it.
How can I access Database on Y from X without using (installing) SQL Server on X.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796&displaylang=en)?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a tool like [SQuirrel SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) (free) or [Aqua Data Studio](http://www.aquafold.com).

Answer (score 4):

One can use the sqlcmd utility.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180944.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You need to install **SQL Server Client tools** on X. From the installation kit choose only Client conectivity tools. It is impossible to access a SQL server from a non SQL server without having at least the Client tools installed on the non-SQL server. You will be able to connect after installing either from SQL management studio or sqlcmd (cmd-line)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sqlwebadmin.codeplex.com](http://sqlwebadmin.codeplex.com/) to access your SQL server from web.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SQL Server Management Studio of Database Y to connect to Database X.  When you are asked to connect to a Database via the "Connect to Server", change the Server Name to Database X.  Enter your credentials and this will connect to the SQL Server on Database X.